# Python Sockets Port forwarding

Tags: python, sockets

So I port forwarded my ip so that my friends can test if my stuff works[image]

And I have a simple server that is hosted on the internal ip

```
import socket
import threading



class Server:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connections = []
    def __init__(self, ip="0.0.0.0", port=5555):
        self.sock.bind((ip, port))
        self.sock.listen(1)

    def handler(self, c, a):
        while True:
            data = c.recv(4096)
            for connection in self.connections:
                connection.send(data)
            if not data:
                print(str(a[0]) + ":" + str(a[1]), "disconnected")
                self.connections.remove(c)
                c.close()
                break

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c, a = self.sock.accept()
            rThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c, a))
            rThread.daemon = True
            rThread.start()
            self.connections.append(c)
            print(str(a[0]) + ":" + str(a[1]), "connected")


host = Server("192.168.x.xxx", 6667)
print("Server status: Running")
host.run()
```

And a simple client module that I attempted to pass the public ip to

```
import socket
import pickle
import threading
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

class Client():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    def __init__(self, address):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.sock.connect((address, 6667))

    def run(self, id):
        RATE = 16000
        CHUNK = 256

        self.id = id

        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        player = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
        while True:
            data = self.sock.recv(4096)
            data = pickle.loads(data)
            if data[0] != self.id:
                if not data:
                    break
                player.write(np.fromstring(data[1],dtype=np.int16),CHUNK)

    def sendMsg(self, data, id):
        data1 = [id, data]
        self.sock.send(pickle.dumps(data1))
```

The client does not connect to the server when I try to give it the public address

```
print("Connecting to server")
cli = Client("91.242.xxx.xxx")
rThread = threading.Thread(target=cli.run, args=(id,))
rThread.daemon = True
rThread.start()
print("Connected to server")
```

The only thing that outputs is `Connecting to server`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what to do to fix this

Comment: When I use the internal Ip everything works fine

Comment: are you trying this from internal network?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the problem is that when binding the socket you are using port 5555 not the port 6677 you use later. But i have only skimmed over your code so can't be certain

Comment: @Ben no when I call the instantance it sets the port to 6667

Comment: @obayhan I tried from LAN network and it didnt work I had to use my private IP and I tried it in a different network and my Private IP and Public still didnt work

Comment: So i had to set the external IP to * to allow people to connect but it still does not work. When I port scan with the private ip it's open (LAN network) but when I port scan with the public IP it says the port is closed

Comment: it seems like it is related with your modem or something else but not your code.

Comment: @obayhan after doing a lot of testing and messing about in discord server we have came to the conclusion that it is infact my modem but I have no idea on how to fix it

Comment: Sorry i confused. Can anybody reach your ports from external metwork or not?

Comment: @obayhan I have solved the issue my ISP uses CGNAT and i simply had to ask them to give me a public IP address

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My ISP uses CGNat and I just had to call them to tell them that I need a public IP and they gladly did it for me.